# Jenkins execute shell scripts with parameters on remote machine

Tags: linux, git, github, jenkins, ssh-agent

I have a Jenkins job which executes a shell script on remote server. Now I would like to send some parameters along with the shell script. Below example might get you more idea.

```
variable1={git-URL}
variable2={branch}
```

I want this parameters to be passed on to shell script which is on remote machine and should execute like below

```
#/usr/local/bin/check_out_code.sh <git-url> <branch>
```

Would be great if anyone can point me some work around for this

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can reference any environment variable, including Jenkins parameters, as any other variable in linux: `${VARNAME}`

Comment: Does these variable get passed to a shell script which gets excuted on remote machine? I will give a try

Comment: The node that is executing the command (master or slave) will expand these variables before executing the command. If the command happens to be a remote script, then the remote script will be executed, with expanded params.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with it.

The parameters`/${xx}/$xxx` are undefined in remote machine. So when your shell script executes in remote machine cannot get the correct value.

This way will fix the problem:

```
ssh -t server.example.com 'export MYVAR='"'$LOCALVAR'"'; mycommand'
```

Comment: In my case the shell script didn't require that much escaping: `ssh 'export MYVAR="'$localvar1"_"$localvar2'";`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Slav you can use environment/build arguments like any other environment variable in Jenkins. One thing to remember is that they get expanded before the script is executed. If you happen to be using pipeline groovy scripts, make sure you use double quotes `"` instead of single `'`:

following will not work:

```
sh '/usr/local/bin/check_out_code.sh ${giturl} ${branch}'
```

following will work:

```
    sh "/usr/local/bin/check_out_code.sh ${giturl} ${branch}"
```